# Using shove to add string to array, still getting empty array

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, rspec

Working on a pig latin challenge. I'm trying to use shove to add string to an array. I'm trying to get this to work of `s = 'apple'`. I want it to find `'a'` in vowels, add `'ay'` making it `'appleay'`, and shove that into pig_latin, then return pig_latin.

```
def translate(s)
  vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
  words = []
  pig_latin = []
  words << s.downcase.split
  for word in words do 
    if vowels.include?(word[0])
      word << 'ay'
      pig_latin << word
    end
  end
  pig_latin
end
```

When I run the rspec test:

```
require "pig_latin"
describe "#translate" do
  it "translates a word beginning with a vowel" do
    s = translate("apple")
    s.should == "appleay"
  end
```

I get:

```
#translate
  translates a word beginning with a vowel (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) #translate translates a word beginning with a vowel
     Failure/Error: s.should == "appleay"
       expected: "appleay"
            got: [] (using ==)
     # ./04_pig_latin/pig_latin_spec.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00064 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./04_pig_latin/pig_latin_spec.rb:24 # #translate translates a word beginning with a vowel
```

What is wrong with my code? Why is this returning an empty array?

Comment: Can you please improved the formatting of your question, including the code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution:

You need to change:

```
words = []
words << s.downcase.split
```

to this:

```
words = s.downcase.split
```

## Explanation:

`String.split()` returns an array so you need to **assign** it to the `words` variable instead of pushing it onto the array.  In the original, you are embedding an array of words into an array making the `words` variable look like this:

```
[["apple"]]
```